# Access to private nested class returned from member function

Tags: c++

Please help me understand why it is possible for a class member function to return a private nested class object, and why it is then possible to call member functions on that private nested class, eg:

```
class Y
{
    class X
    {
    public:
        void f() { cout << "Hello World" << endl; }
    };

public:
    X g() { return X(); }
};

void h()
{
    Y::X x;     // Error, as expected: class Y::X is private.
    x.f();      // Error.

    Y y;        // OK.
    y.g().f();  // OK. But why???
}
```

I tested with GCC and Visual C++, and that last line compile on both. I cannot seem to find anything in the C++ standard that would make this valid. Any ideas why this works?

**Edit:**

Another observation:

```
void i()
{
    Y y;

    Y::X x2 = y.g(); // Error: class Y::X is private
    x2.f();          // Error

    auto x3 = y.g(); // OK
    x3.f();          // OK
}
```

Comment: Both functions are `public` and you actually aren't using `X` anywhere.

Comment: The definition of `X` is private, but function `g()` is public. So there is no problem at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Making a nested class `private` doesn't mean external scopes can never use an instance of that class. Access specifiers affect *names*, and your `main` function never attempts to *name* `Y::X`.<sup>1</sup> The only place where `Y::X` is named is within `Y`, which of course has access to its own `private` members. That the function returns an instance of `Y::X` to `main` isn't particularly relevant.

> `[C++14: 11/1]:` A member of a class can be
>
> - `private`; that is, **its *name* can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is declared**.
> - `protected`; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is declared, by classes derived from that class, and by their friends (see 11.4).
> - `public`; that is, its name can be used anywhere without access restriction.

Admittedly, the standard does not have any text to explicitly unconfuse you and point out that access to the entities themselves is not controlled by these keywords, but that is definitely the intent and, ultimately, as far as the legalese goes.

<sub><sup>1</sup> It does name `Y::X::f`, but that name is `public`.</sub>

Comment: Now I'm curious:  would it have been possible to store the result of `g()` in a variable before the introduction of `auto`?

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I don't see how.

Comment: Interesting.  I didn't realise that `auto` allowed declarations that would be otherwise impossible.  I always thought `auto` is mainly a convenience feature.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: It's pretty convenient to be able to declare something that wasn't previously declarable. Frankly I think this is a terrible inconsistency that contributes to `auto`'s awfulness, but there we go.

Answer (score 2):

> why it is possible for a class member function to return a private nested class object

A nested class is a class member too, and the member function has the access right on the private member.

> and why it is then possible to call member functions on that private nested class

You're not using the private nested class name here, i.e. `Y::X`. And `Y::X::f()` is a public function, so it's possible to call it directly.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the example that you are looking for. `f1` is public, `f2` is private and triggers the error you are expecting:

```
#include <iostream>

class Y
{
    class X
    {
        public:
            void f1() { std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; }
        private:
            void f2() { std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl; }
    };

    public:
        X g() { return X(); }
};

int main()
{
    // Y::X x;     // Error, as expected: class Y::X is private.
    // x.f();      // Error.

    Y y;         // OK.
    y.g().f1();  // OK. Because f1 is public.
    y.g().f2();  // Error. Because f2 is private.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP was wondering why `y.g()` worked, as much as anything... especially as they went out of their way to show that we can get actually instance a `Y::X` as long as we avoid naming its type, using `auto`.

Comment: Maybe. In that case my answer can be removed. Let the OP decide.