# type defined in free function, accessible through auto outside. Language Bug or Feature?

Tags: c++, c++14

Let's define a class inside a free function, and access it outside:

```
#include <iostream>
auto myFunc(){
    class MyType{public: int i = 0; int j = 1;};
    return MyType();
}
int main() {
    auto my_type = myFunc();
    std::cout << my_type.i << " " << my_type.j << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles, run as expected:

```
0 1
```

The name MyType is properly hidden:
if we replace auto, the following won't compile:

```
int main() {
    MyType my_type = myFunc();
    std::cout << my_type.i << " " << my_type.j << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

What does the standard say about it?

How to prevent it? The following code did not help:

```
 namespace{
auto myFunc(){
    class MyType{public: int i = 0; int j = 1;};
    return MyType();
}
}
int main() {
    auto my_type = myFunc();
    std::cout << my_type.i << " " << my_type.j << "\n";
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to prevent it? What's the problem?

Comment: How would you use the returned object if you had no access to its members? Or do you mean preventing the exposure of a local class instance?

Comment: Well, not really that I want to prevent it. It is just a surprising case for me, and I would like to know if there's a workaround.

Comment: A workaround for what? What's the problem?

Comment: no problem. A misunderstanding: I would have expected not to be able to use myType out of the scope of myFunc.

Comment: @DariusZuCH: Okay. Just remember: scope is for _names_. You're not using `myType`'s name here, so it's fine. I agree that it _appears_ like it's a bit of a "hole" opened by `auto`, but it's not really. Only `myFunc` has the ability to expose anything related to that type anyway, so you lose no "security".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard doesn't say anything about this specifically, except that — as you've already pointed out — it's the *name* that has a scope, not the type. Use of `auto` bypasses the type's name, giving you a way to get at the type regardless of the name's scope.

It's kind of similar to how [making a nested class `private` doesn't mean you can't use instances of it, only that you can't name it outside of the encapsulating class's scope](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33197942/560648).

I don't see how you'd "prevent" it, nor why you'd want to.